# How can I repair a shattered clay pot lid?

Tags: glue

I dropped a clay lid and it broke cleanly in two pieces. Is there a way to glue it back together? I don't mind it that the break will be visible, while the pot looks good too, I mostly use it for practical reasons.

This pot is used in an oven at 200°C for long times (sometimes up to 2 hours), and then washed per hand, sometimes soaked in water. Whatever repair method I use, it should hold in these conditions. It is a rather porous clay/earthenware, I don't know if there is a glue which will work in this situation.

[image: broken lid]
[image: break]

Sorry for the bad lighting, but if you look just below the handle in the second picture (the part which is slightly turned away from the camera), you can see the clay structure better.

Comment: Pedantic, I know, but *shattered* implies many more pieces than just two. This lid is simply *broken*.

Answer (score 5):

White glue (Polyvinyl acetate) will fail in the oven.
So will regular superglue ([cyanoacrylates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate)).

However, there *are* specialty [Cyanoacrylate Adhesives that are good up to 250°C (480°F)](http://www.permabond.com/en/en-cyanoacrylate-selector.htm).  Look around, you may be able to find something at a reasonable price.

Epoxies, liquid nails and the like do not seem to me a safe choice to use near food.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need a [food safe epoxy](http://www.masterbond.com/properties/food-safe-adhesives-sealants-coatings-encapsulation-compounds) - food safe and rated up to 450F.  I haven't had much luck with CA glue for ceramics in the past.  I'd try to find a specific one for you, but I don't know whats available in Germany.